# strrev and array_map how to use them?

Tags: php, array-map

got it myself more text needed here for the reason just beeing here so it will not make sense sry but i solved it myself

```
function mw($text, $width) 
{
    $wrapped = wordwrap( $text, $width, "\n" );
    $lines = explode( "\n", $wrapped );
    foreach ( $lines as $line ) 
    { 
        $leers = "";
        $num_leers = $width - strlen( $line );
        if ( $num_leers > 0 ) {
            $leers = str_repeat ( " " , $num_leers );
        }
        echo "- $line$leers -<br>";
    }
}
```

output:

```
 - ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. - 
 - Nunc placerat, mauris et tempor pharetra, tellus   - 
 - felis vestibulum tortor, at porta dui lectus       - 
 - non ante. Maecenas fringilla, enim et elementum    - 
 - dignissim, leo urna commodo magna, quis laoreet    - 
 - nisl mi ut sapien. Proin porttitor pellentesque    - 
 - lobortis. Morbi cursus tellus ornare magna         -
```

Comment: Please proof-read your question, it's very hard to read and I'm no typo fetishist at all. Just activate the spell-checker in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the 1st line jsut one word?

Because you reverse the array and the prior last entry (the shortest one, here one word) becomes the first entry.

The code is just doing what you have told. As you have not given any information what the function *should* do (specification). Just blindly modifying a function cut and pasted from some internet site because you thought it's half through is not a good idea.

First think about how you can solve a problem, then start to code.

Comment: even if you helped me you will not get credit from me for that. that the way i code i am not good at coding and logic at this pint so i copy and paste and learn by doing. if i have questions i can ask them, thats what stack overflow is for. i taught about the problem and even posted it here. the best andswer was a link to the site so thats where i started.

Comment: Please don't feel offended, I just wanted to highlight that with copy-and-pasting code you can run into problems you don't understand. As you've not shared what the function is for (specification of it), there's not much more I can help you with but to answer your partial question. It might work for you if your remove `strrev` and `array_reverse` calls from your function.